# Horizontal RecyclerView и Vertical RecyclerView

Tags: android, adapter, recyclerview

во фрагменте имеются горизонтальный и вертикальный RecyclewVIew. Для каждого из них есть свой адаптер. При прокрутке вниз скроллится только вертикальный recycler, при это горизонтальный, как стоял сверху, так и стоит. как сделать так, что прокрутка вниз-вверх скроллила весь фрагмент, а не только один recycler?

Answer (score 1):

Есть два варианта:

1. Запихнуть оба `RecyclerView` в вертикальный `ScrollView` и задать для вертикального `RecyclerView` высоту в `wrap_content`. Но это плохой вариант если в вертикальном `RecyclerView` много элементов, ибо они все будут постоянно присутствовать в разметке, а не создаваться/удаляться по мере прокрутки.
2. Сделать горизонтальный `RecyclerView` первым элементом вертикального. Этот вариант наиболее правильный, но возможно будет немного сложнее в реализации. Хотя ничего сильно сложного тут нет.